# VBA - Search Column for "average" & "StDev" - if found copy whole column to new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to search through my worksheet for all columns that contain either `average` or `Stdev` in `row 7`, and if they do copy the whole column to a new worksheet. I have tried the following code but it only seems to copy one of the columns and not all within the worksheet.

```
Sub FindAverage()

    Dim c As Range    
    Set c = Rows(7).Find("*Average*", LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If c Is Nothing Then
      Exit Sub
    ElseIf Not c Is Nothing Then
      Columns(c.Column).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("A:A")
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

End Sub
```

I would really appreciate any help you could offer.

Comment: you mean containm cells with `Average` and `StDev` in their formula ? or just a regular `String` ?

Comment: Hi just a regular string Average and StDev are headers of some columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `Find` to search for 2 values, is not "built-in", you will need to write some extra code.

The code below, uses the `Find` function to find all "Average" in the range. So you need to run another loop to find also "StDev".

```
Sub FindAverage()

Dim c As Range
Dim col As Long
Dim firstAddress As String

With Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows(7)
    Set c = .Find("*Average*", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        col = 1
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Columns(c.Column).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet4").Columns(col)

        Do
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            If c Is Nothing Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

            C.EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet4").Columns(col)                   
            col = col + 1
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

---

**Option 2**: Use a regular loop inside the occupied range in Row 7:

```
Sub FindAverageansStdev()

Dim C As Range
Dim col As Long, LastCol As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    LastCol = .Cells(7, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column '<-- get last column with data in row 7
    col = 1
    For Each C In .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(7, LastCol)) ' <-- loop through occupied cells only in row 7
        If C.Value Like "*Average*" Or C.Value Like "*StDev*" Then
            C.EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet4").Columns(col)    
            ' option to pastespecial (values only)
            C.EntireColumn.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet4").Columns(col).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues             
            col = col + 1
        End If
    Next C
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thats perfect thanks! Just one last query how do I paste the values and not the formula?

Comment: Thanks you very much Shai, your help is really appreciated.

Comment: @Dave you're welcome :) please mark as "answer" , by clicking on the **V** next to my answer (the V should turn green)